# Cannot drag Yii CGridview row after update

Tags: php, yii, jquery-ui-sortable, cgridview

I am using below link for sorting CGridview row,

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/238/creating-a-jqueryui-sortable-cgridview/

its working fine, but after grid update i cannot able to drag the grid row !

My code,

```
$('#basefilter-grid table').sortable({
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            forceHelperSize: true,
            items: 'tr',
            update : function () {
                serial = $('#basefilter-grid table').sortable('serialize', {key: 'order[]', attribute: 'class'});
                $.ajax({
                    'url': '" . $this->createUrl('baseContact/orderFilterRow') . "',
                    'type': 'post',
                    'data': serial,
                    'success': function(data){

                          $.fn.yiiGridView.update('basefilter-grid');

                    },
                    'error': function(request, status, error){
                        alert('We are unable to set the sort order at this time.  Please try again in a few minutes.');
                    }
                });
            },
            helper: fixHelper
        }).disableSelection();
```

I have column 'order' after row dragged its gets updated, after grid refresh only updated value will be seen, so i need to update grid badly, can anyone say how to do this?

Comment: Is there any errors in your browser console log?

Comment: no errors just i cant drag the grid row after grid update!! !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is. If you have any javascript or CSS added to the view where your grid lives, they may not be available after the `ajaxUpdate`. I suggest you re-activate the plugins or extra JS functionality used for drag'n'drop.

For Example, if you want to use bootstrap tooltips you need to re-activate them after the ajaxUpdate:

```
'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'function(id,data) { $("[rel=\"tooltip\"]").tooltip(); }',
```